Flask cannot get Chinese args
I have build a flask app in docker from nvidia/cuda:12.5.1-cudnn-runtime-ubuntu22.04. But this flask cannot receive any utf-8 request with the Bad request syntax error.
# here the messy code ä½\xa0å¥½ is 你好 in Chinese, which means hello
code 400, message Bad request syntax ('GET /chat?question=ä½\xa0å¥½ HTTP/1.1')

For English characters that the query question=hello, everything works fine. I tried to set app.json.ensure_ascii = False and set the charset=UTF-8 in curl, but got the same error.
However, when I launch the app with gunicorn, it works. By the way, I set the locales of the docker image to Chinese, so probably it's not the system problem.
This is the demo code of test.py:
from flask import Flask, request
from loguru import logger
app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.ensure_ascii = False
@app.route("/chat", methods=["GET"])
def chat():
    query = request.args.get("question")
    logger.info(f"用户提问： {query}", enqueue=True)
    print(query)
    return query

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return "你好"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=10132, debug=True)

And I run this demo snippet with python test.py.
The request by curl is simply curl  --request GET 'http://172.18.0.3:10132/chat?question=你好. Then I got this error:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 400</p>
        <p>Message: Bad request syntax ('GET /chat?question=ä½\xa0å¥½ HTTP/1.1').</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 400 - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
    </body>
</html>

Other informations that may be helpful:
# OS Which is followed the container nvidia/cuda:12.5.1-cudnn-runtime-ubuntu22.04
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

# Flask version, it is installed through conda
flask                     3.0.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge

# Python version
python                    3.11.9          hb806964_0_cpython    conda-forge


Please [edit] to provide code which unambiguously represents a request which should be handled, bpt isn't. See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].
